# javascript: span around last two words in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

Using javascript, I'm trying to insert a span around the last 2 words of a string.

Using the below regular expression I can get the last word, but I can't figure out how to get the last 2 words.

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+?)$/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

Comment: You can try the following regular expression: `/(\w+\s+\w+)$/`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a second `\w` separated by a space, so

```
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+\s\w+?)$/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

if you can have multiple spaces, make that optional

```
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+\s+\w+?)$/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```

Answer (score 4):

Break the text down into words and use the `slice` method to find all words except the last two, and the last two words.

```
var words = $div.text().split(' ');

$div.html(words.slice(0, words.length - 2).join(' ') + " " + "<span class='bold'>" + 
words.slice(words.length-2, words.length).join(' ') + "</span>");
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rjs4gac1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to check for another word `\w+` and a whitespace character (or more) `\s+`  between them:

```
$div.html($div.text().replace(/(\w+\s+\w+?)$/, '<span>$1</span>'));
```